# What is an ASP.NET Web App with MVC Angular and Kendo?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, asp.net-mvc

The job I am on now is working on an old ASP.NET web application that was previously purchased and built by a company outside of the United States.

Our company has several customers that use this website for their company's products.

A few years ago, my company decided to start doing the work locally instead of overseas, and I was hired on a few months ago to help catch up on several bugs that customers have reported.

Since I have been working here, I have found that the main part of the solution is an ***ASP.NET** Web Application* with a **Master.Page**.

Some of the pages, however, follow the MVC structure, but some of the Models in the MVC simply return .aspx pages and have no View or Controller.

Still other pages are created using Angular with a Kendo plug-in. Most of the code for these is located in a dedicated folder, and it is all javascript that displays independently or using an ASP.NET page or MVC structure.

I'm trying to get up to speed on MVC and Angular, but this project does not follow the structure that I find whenever I follow tutorials.

A lot of the Angular displays in an iframe, so it doesn't appear in the browser's URL and can be tricky to find the source code for.

Does this ring a bell for anyone? Is this a known type of project that I could research online to understand how it flows?

When I try to make a new project in Visual Studio 2019, there are numerous project types that I have no experience with (ASP.NET Core Web App, Blazor App, gRPC Service, etc.).

Sadly, I can't just look at the Project Properties page and tell what type of solution it is.

How do I find out what this project is called? Hopefully, that will help with my development.

[image: Project Screenshot]

Comment: Regular old `web forms`. Which BTW can contain MVC. The fact they used iframes makes me cringe though. Good luck sir.

Comment: People can do whatever with their web apps. For apps that have been around a few years, they haven't necessarily followed a single paradigm. There's not necessarily a name for your specific conglomeration, or a specific resource. You'll just have to refer to the appropriate documentation for Kendo/MVC/Web Forms depending on what part of the app you're looking at. Stack Overflow isn't here to find that documentation for you.

Comment: @mason - I was just wanting to know if this is some technique that has a name that I can research instead of having to chase down different bits and pieces.

Comment: I understand the question and answered it for you. Unless you need additional clarification, I suggest you delete this. It's just not a good fit for Stack Overflow.